# Unity rendering

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rendering

Hello so i want to ask a question i have a sniper and in most games wen you zoom with sniper the gun is gone but i and most people use 2 cameras 1 is for the world and the other is for only weapons so we have a layer weapon and wen i zoom in and lets say i disable the gunCamera (camera that only renders weapons) so we have a player infront of us with his gun that is with a layer weapon i wont see his weapon how can i fix it . Here is the script (i tried to just reduce the fiel of view that wont work too):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sniper : MonoBehaviour {

    private float range;
    private float damage;

    private GameObject scope;
    private GameObject crossHair;
    private bool isScoped;
    private bool canFire;

    private GameObject weaponCamera;
    private Camera gunCamera;
    private Camera fpsCamera;
    private float normalFOV;
    private float zoomFOV;
    private float zoomGunFov;
    private float normalGunFov;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Awake()
    {
        fpsCamera = Camera.main;
        canFire = true;
        isScoped = false;
        weaponCamera = transform.parent.parent.gameObject.transform.Find("GunCamera").gameObject;
        crossHair = transform.parent.parent.parent.parent.gameObject.transform.Find("CrossHairs").gameObject.transform.Find("cursor").gameObject;
        scope = transform.parent.parent.parent.parent.gameObject.transform.Find("CrossHairs").gameObject.transform.Find("scope").gameObject;
    }
    void Start() {
        gunCamera = weaponCamera.GetComponent<Camera>();
        crossHair.SetActive(false);
        scope.SetActive(false);
        damage = 100f;
        range = 10000f;
        zoomFOV = 15f;
        zoomGunFov = 1f;
        normalFOV = fpsCamera.fieldOfView;
        normalGunFov = gunCamera.fieldOfView;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        Shoot();
        Zoom();
    }

    private void Shoot()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && canFire)
        {
            ShootRay();
            StartCoroutine(ReloadShot());
        }
    }

    private void Zoom()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
        {
            isScoped = !isScoped;
            scope.SetActive(isScoped);

        }

        if (isScoped)
        {
            OnScoped();
        }
        else
        {
            NotScoped();
        }
    }

    private void OnScoped()
    { 
        fpsCamera.fieldOfView = zoomFOV;
        gunCamera.fieldOfView = zoomGunFov;
    }

    private void NotScoped()
    {
        fpsCamera.fieldOfView = normalFOV;
        gunCamera.fieldOfView = normalGunFov;
    }

    private void ShootRay()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(fpsCamera.transform.position,fpsCamera.transform.forward,out hit, range))
        {
            Health_Armor target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Health_Armor>();

            if (target != null)
            {
                target.TakeDamage(damage);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        isScoped = false;
        scope.SetActive(false);
        crossHair.SetActive(true);
        fpsCamera.fieldOfView = normalFOV;
        gunCamera.fieldOfView = normalGunFov;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {      
        canFire = true;
        crossHair.SetActive(false);
    }

    IEnumerator ReloadShot()
    {
        canFire = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        canFire = true;

    }


}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The only weapon that should be visible to your second camera is the player's *own* weapon. There is no reason to make *other player's* weapons an overlay.

Comment: yea im talking about multiplayer

Comment: so both players are the same they have the same camera same weapon layers everything @Draco18s

Comment: You're doing it wrong. The local player should always be treated differently from the other players. Always. Why? Because those other players are only *copies,* they're not the real thing.

Comment: yea i have to get more into that so if you can tell me what it means like how do i treat it diffrently ?

Comment: You already know which player is the local player. Only tag/set layer on their gun.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 layers, ex :

- WeaponPlayer - for the localPlayer, set this layer by script only on the local player
- WeaponOpponent - for the other player, set it as default

And set your Zoomed camera to do not render WeaponPlayer